# whitelist AAD login endpoint

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, adal

We have a SPA which authenticates using ADAL (similar to examples provided https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp). Now we want to host our application inside a secure environment where all communication outside is blocked by default. So we want to whitelist IP addresses which are/can be associated with AAD login process.

Using DNS lookup to find IP addresses for login.microsoftonline.com doesn't give me all the IPs since I did nslookup from different location and found different set. So, wondering do you guys know a set of such IPs.

PS: I found a list of IPs here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-prerequisites but this list is huge. Do I need to whitelist all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, you should whitelist all IPs in the [Office 365 URLs and IP address ranges - Identity and Authentication](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-365-URLs-and-IP-address-ranges-8548a211-3fe7-47cb-abb1-355ea5aa88a2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bkmk_identity_ip) documentation.**

This list is so big because Azure AD is a globally available service and thus is deployed across the world in order to meet its availability and performance SLAs. Also worth mentioning is that Azure AD is comprised of many different services (Auth, MFA, Azure AD Connect, etc) which have their own IP addresses.

Lastly, **don't forget to also add the IP address of any federation server(s) if the Azure AD tenant is federated** (this is generally ADFS). This last point is particularly challenging if your applications is a multitenant application.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do we have a list of IP addresses to whitelist for graph.windows.net?